# State machine of a coffee machine

Tags: state-machines, homework

[image]I can not solve this exercise. I really need help.

> Design a coffee vending machine with the following specifications:
>
> 1. Each coffee costs 15 c. The only output from the state machine, Y, changes from '0' to '1' when 15 c or greater has already been entered.
> 2. Accepts coins of 5c or 10c (cents), and does not give change (that is, 2 coins of 10c are accepted and correctly processed). Thus, the state machine has two inputs, I5 and I10.
> 3. After "delivering" a coffee, the state machine restarts (the transition will depend on whether or not new currency is being introduced).
> 4. Two or more coins are not accepted simultaneously (the machine only has one slot).
>
> A. Draw the diagram and the state transition table of the machine.
>
> B. Perform state machine with flip-flops D, using the standard technique in state coding (i.e. states are encoded directly to binary, and associated with flip flops outputs). Draw the logic circuit.
>
> C. Perform state machine with flip flops D, using the 1-hot technique in state coding. Draw the logic circuit.

Comment: This is clearly a homework problem. What have you tried so far, and what point are you stuck on?

Comment: @DaveTweed I tried to draw the state machine, but I do not know if I'm doing well and I don't know how to restart the machine, like "finishing the cycle".

Comment: exactly. Show us what you've got so far. It's much, much easier to help someone with a non-perfect approach then to give a complete lesson on state machines.

Comment: What you have in the diagram is a Moore state machine.  Have you also learned about Mealy state machines?  You might find that helpful...

Comment: @Radian We only learn Moore's machines and the teacher wants us to do this with a Moore machine.

Comment: OK, Mealy is out....  You have 2 states -- 15c and 20c -- where the output is 1.  In each of these 2 states: if you get a 5c coin, go to the 5c state; if you get a 10c coin, go to the 10c state.  Does that help?

Comment: @Radian 20c state? 2 states?  Not helping.  4 states: Idle, 5c, 10c, and dispense.  First coin goes to 5c or 10c, 5c+I5 = 10c, 5c+I10=dispense, 10c+(I5 or I10)=dispense

Comment: @Radian I made a new state diagram and the states table. Can you check if it's correct, please?

Comment: No, too many states, no 20c, no 15c, your transitions should be labeled I5 and I10, there is no X.  Combine 15c and 20c into a dispense state.  There should only be a single transition exiting any state, except 10c which will have both I5 and I10 exiting.

Comment: @Misunderstood I do not understand. Can you draw me the diagram that you are talking about and paste in the post, please? I considered I5 as X = 0 and I10 as X = 1 to be able to do the states table.

Comment: @Misunderstood - your handle is fitting.  You really didn't understand the OP's state diagram.  OP had states representing (and labeled) 20c and 15c. If you can't understand that, you're probably in the wrong forum.  I didn't re-factor OP's state machine, I am trying to guide.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález - apologies - for some reason I thought coffee was 20c, not 15c...

Comment: @Radian  It's Misunderstood not Misunderstands.  What you said was confusing the issue.  There cannot be only two states at any time.  You have the current state and the two states to transition to.  You need the current state to loop back to the current state when the input values do not exit to another state. There is no need to get snarky.  If I make a mistake, point it out politely.

Comment: @Misunderstood Sorry, but I did not understand how to do it, it seemed very confusing. Yes, it has to be done with Moore's machine, because the teacher said that in this discipline we were only going to talk about Moore machines and we were not going to use Mealy's machine. But even then I did not realize why the circuit I drew is wrong and how to do it right. Please, I would like you to post the diagram you are suggesting, because this way I think I will understand.

Comment: @Radian Could you please tell me what's wrong with the Moore machine I drew? And if there's anything wrong, could you please put your diagram on Moore's machine?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I started an answer.  Draw what you can, then edit my post, and add a photo of your drawing.

Comment: @Misunderstood My drawing is in the post. I have not realized yet why my drawing is wrong and I did not realize the answer. The problem in question has to be made with Moore's machine.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález I am suggesting you start over.  What you have is beyond repair.  Please start over.

Comment: @Misunderstood I do not understand what you want me to do. You are telling me that on the arrows during transitions I have to write 00/0, 01/0 and 10/0, but how can I identify the I5 and I10 on the arrows?

Comment: @Misunderstood How does a person who sees my state machine know that the 01/0 transition corresponds to putting a 5-cent coin in the slot (I5) or a 10-cent coin in the slot (I10)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem statement is somewhat ambiguous, but given that the suggested technology is D FFs, I think we can assume that we're talking about a synchronous state machine with a clock, and that the I5 and I10 inputs are pulses that are 1 clock wide. We are told that both inputs can't be active at the same time.

Therefore, the basic conceptual state machine just needs to keep track of how much money we've received so far, until it reaches enough to pay for a coffee:

```
     +----------------------------------------------+
     V                                              |
+------+      +------+      +------+      +------+  |
| idle | I5   |  5c  | I5   | 10c  | I5   | 15c  |  |
|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=1 |--+
+------+      +------+      +------+      +------+
  I10|          I10|         ^ I10|         ^ ^
     +-----------------------+    +---------+ |
                   |                          |
                   +--------------------------+
```

Note that since we aren't required to make change, the 15c state really means "15 or 20 cents received", either of which is enough to dispense a coffee. But giving change when we receive 20 cents just requires one more state (and one more output).

Implementing this abstract Moore state machine as either binary-coded D FFs or one-hot D FFs is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

EDIT: You seem to be making an earnest effort, so here's the next step of the analysis. I don't understand your notation for the state transition table, so I'll draw it the way I would approach it, where each line of this table corresponds to one transition in the diagram, with the "null" transitions (both inputs = 0) made explicit.

```
Current    Inputs     Next
 State    I5   I10    State
------   ---   ---   ------
 idle     0     0     idle
 idle     1     0      5c
 idle     0     1     10c
  5c      0     0      5c
  5c      1     0     10c
  5c      0     1     15c
 10c      0     0     10c
 10c      1     0     15c
 10c      0     1     15c
 15c      x     x     idle
```

Note that I'm still using abstract names for the states; whether these map to binary values or one-hot encoding is still up to you. Once you pick the mapping, the actual logic required to produce the actual D input values for each FF should fall directly out of the process.

---

EDIT #2: OK, taking into account the parenthetical comments on Specifications 2 and 3, it seems we need to keep track of overpayments and additional coins being introduced even while the coffee is being dispensed. Therefore the state diagram and transition table need to be modified:

```
                 +--------------------------------------------------+
                 |             +------------------------------+     |
     +-----------|-------------|--------------------+         |     |
     |           | +-----------|---------------+    |I5=0     |     |I5=0
     |           | |           | +----------+  |    |& I10=0  |     |& I10=0
     V           V V           V V       I10|  |I5  |       I5|     |
+------+      +------+      +------+      +------+  |     +------+  |
| idle | I5   |  5c  | I5   | 10c  | I5   | 15c  |--+  I10| 20c  |--+
|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=0 |----->|  Y=1 |<-------|  Y=1 |
+------+      +------+      +------+      +------+        +------+
  I10|          I10|         ^ I10|           ^             ^
     +-------------|---------+    +-----------|-------------+
                   +--------------------------+
```

Now, the machine will correctly dispense two coffees if you put three 10-cent coins into it. And now there are no unlabeled (unconditional) transitions.

```
Current    Inputs     Next
 State    I5   I10    State
------   ---   ---   ------
 idle     0     0     idle
 idle     1     0      5c
 idle     0     1     10c
  5c      0     0      5c
  5c      1     0     10c
  5c      0     1     15c
 10c      0     0     10c
 10c      1     0     15c
 10c      0     1     20c
 15c      0     0     idle
 15c      1     0      5c
 15c      0     1     10c
 20c      0     0      5c
 20c      1     0     10c
 20c      0     1     15c
```

---

FINAL EDIT (hopefully):

The output is only a function of the state, so calculating the output logic uses a different K-map from the one you use to calculate the transitions. The state assignment for the simpler 4-state machine might look like this:

```
State       Q1  Q0   Y
-----       --  --   -
 idle        0   0   0
  5c         0   1   0
 10c         1   0   0
 15c         1   1   1
```

Obviously, Y is simply Q0 AND Q1.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have attached an image to the post with the indication that you gave me. Could you confirm that the state diagram is correct this time? I'll try to make the states table and the circuit and then I'll post. I wish you'd tell me later if I did okay.

Comment: I did not realize why it is that when you get to state 15c puts an arrow that goes back to the iddle state, but without any caption at the top of the arrow. After having the money to drink a coffee if a 5-cent coin were introduced, should not there be an arrow linking 15c to 5c and having a caption I5? And another that united 15c to 10c and had I10 legend?

Comment: No. A single unlabeled transition out of a state simply means that the transition is unconditional, and that you only stay in that state for one clock cycle. When you get to the 15c state, you essentially pulse the Y output for one clock cycle to dispense the coffee and then go back to the idle state to wait for any additional coins from the next customer.

Comment: And what do I put in the state table in that case? Usually I make a state table where I put the current states in binary code and fill in the following states in binary code as well, but I separate case I5 and I10 according to the transition they make. How do I make the 15 c case since it is unconditional?

Comment: You put "don't cares" in the input columns for that transition.

Comment: I did the state table of the machine. Could you tell me if the table is well-made so I can do Karnaugh's maps, please?

Comment: Where we put do not care in the transition from 15c to idle we put the value of 1 in the output variable as in the drawing?

Comment: @DaveTweed My teacher says that if we do not specify whether it is synchronous or asynchronous, we must always consider it to be synchronous.

Comment: @DaveTweed Is the state table well made?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález: I'm not sure, because I'm not completely following your notation. See my edit above.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález While coffee is being delivered coins can be entered as stated in the description of the state machine.

Comment: @DaveTweed I realize your notation and do not know how to do Karnaugh's maps with her. In the notation I have used, Q1 ^ n and Q0 ^ n correspond to the current states. I called the idle state, the binary code 00; The state 5c is called 01, the state 10c is called 10 and the state 15c is called 11.
In the notation I have used Q1^(n + 1) and Q0^(n + 1) corresponds to the next state, that is, to the state occupied after the transition and the variable Y is the output which will only be 1 when the coffee is served.

Comment: @DaveTweed The future states, ie, Q1 ^ (n + 1) and Q0 ^ (n + 1) are divided for the two cases, one for when we follow transition I5 and another for when we follow transition I10. Let us imagine the first line in which we are in the idle state, so the values ​​Q1 ^ and n0Q0 ^ n are 0 and 0. If we follow I5 we will go to state 5c which corresponds to the binary code 01. If we do not choose I5, but choose I10, let Stops the state 10c which corresponds to the binary code 10. As yet the coffee is not ready because the machine does not have enough money the output variable Y is 0.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for the edit. I think that the transition I5 = 0 & I10 = 0 is not necessary since in the statement say that if the person enters 20 cents it will not have change, therefore, those 5 cents will not accumulate in the machine.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález: No, that transition is necessary, because that's how you get back to the idle state if no new coins are introduced while dispensing coffee. And a strict interpretation of *"that is, 2 coins of 10c are accepted and **correctly processed**"* requires that we keep track of the 5 cents credit left over when somebody puts 20 cents in.

Comment: @DaveTweed But so if I put 20 cents I take a cup of coffee. But the person next to me just has to pay 10 cents only.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález: Exactly! It's called "[paying it forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pay_it_forward)" -- just like when the person in front of you at the toll gate pays your toll for you. After all, if a single customer wants to buy two coffees, but only has dimes, he'd be pretty pissed if he had to put four of them in instead of three, right?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55643/discussion-on-answer-by-dave-tweed-state-machine-of-a-coffee-machine).